# How do you update a website once it has gone live?

Tags: development, cms, workflow

How do you push updates live to templates and modules once you have gone live with the site?

We tend to do a few different solutions as we develop on one site and then akeeba backup to push the site first live. Following that though, to repeat this process again means destroying the old site.

One solution is obviously just ftp up the different files, templates, css, images etc but this is not that quick and some links might break for a few minutes until its done.

Another is to use git hub where we have the code but we are a small team so working on to many branches and releases can make project too much work to be clear to have master be the only version to go live to update.

Basically any tips or solution to putting things on a staging site and then pushing them to live while the live site will be having articles and user registration, etc put in as a live site so cant be replaced.

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply install the extension or template again (without uninstalling the original) by uploading it to the Extension Manager.

We typically create fully installable extensions for our sites. We install them on our development server for testing, and when they are suitable, we simply install them on the production server. As long as the method in the [manifest file](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files) is set to update, you can quickly update your existing extensions simply by uploading them to the Extension Manager.

Working in this way allows us to update the production site without any downtime and ensures that the database data on the production server remains untouched (unless we elect to change it through an update script or SQL file).

Comment: So do the updates and then package it up as a zip and reinstall. So "update" stops it resetting the db data? That's helpful

Comment: @tristanbailey I create the extension package and then perform all of my updates within it. So even on the development server, each time I post an update it is a fully installable extension. When you update, the only way the database tables specific to your extension will change is if you elect to change them either through [database update files](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Managing_Component_Updates_%28Update_SQL_files%29) or [a script file](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file).

Answer (score 6):

There are some free and paid extensions that can help with staging.

**EasyStaging** is a free extension from Craig Phillips (who is an active member on this forum): http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/hosting-a-servers/database-management/21308

**SP Staging** is a paid extension from SP Cyend: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-monitoring/20396

Some web hosting companies are also now providing tools to help with staging.

**SiteGround**: http://blog.siteground.com/siteground-staging

**Rochen**: http://blog.rochenhost.com/2011/11/creating-a-joomla-staging-site

Comment: Thanks @Neil I knew Rochen and SiteGround did something at a larger scale but not the other two. We found Rochen not run so reliably for us so moved last year