# Single source many Joomla sites on a server. How could it be possible?

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

I have hundreds of identical joomla installations on same server. For two years, I have been updating and maintaining them seperately which makes me too tired and causes too much time and energy loss.
Because I do not have time I only want to get suggestions if you have tried something like my intention:

I want to upload all joomla core files/folders to one directory on the server. Then all remaining sites will have only configuration.php and images folder.

With this situation, I will be able to centralize the maintenance.

Is this possible? If so what are the drawbacks?

Comment: Have to admit I'm interested the know how this would turn out. At first, the word "problematic" springs to mind. I think it will also cause major server loading issues as you will have all your Joomla sites trying to pull data from 1 core location

Answer (score 2):

I would use a service like watchful. It allows to update many sites in one go or even automatically updates them for you.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the solution you're looking for, but there are [several Multi Site extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites) that will let you run multiple sites on a single database (and a single Joomla installation). The advantage is the same that you mention: easier to keep everything up to date.

I have to admit I haven't used any of them myself, as I'm a little concerned about security (one site hacked = all sites hacked), and I personally prefer to keep each Joomla installation on it's own cPanel account, but the idea is very interesting. Some users also mention that it's complicated to configure.

Other than that, as @Bakual pointed out, I've heard lot's of good words about [Watchful.li](https://watchful.li/) when it comes to keeping multiple sites up to date.