# Can i use different site using one Joomla installation?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am trying to use same Joomla files for two different website.

is it ok?
Please guide me regarding this.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Omkar

Comment: This question has been asked before. Please search before posting https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/multiple-website-managment-with-joomla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Joomla Multi-Sites

Yes, it is possible to use 1 single installation of Joomla files to run 2 or more different sites. This is the so called multi-sites scenario.

There are extensions the provide this possibility, but it is also possible with the core. Each option has its own pros and cons and possibilities.

Under certain scenarios, it's also possible to share database data (e.g. articles, or single sign-on for users among the shared sites).

The following resources will help you with your research:

### Joomla Docs

- [**Multiple Domains and Web Sites in a single Joomla! Installation**](https://docs.joomla.org/Multiple_Domains_and_Web_Sites_in_a_single_Joomla!_installation)
- [**Multi-site Design Options**](https://docs.joomla.org/Multi-site_Design_Options)

### Extensions

- [**Virtual Domains**](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/virtual-domains/)
- [**JMS Multi-Sites**](https://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/multi-sites/)
- [**AlterBrains Mighty Sites**](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/mightysites/)
- [**Seblod Multisites feature**](https://www.seblod.com/resources/manuals/advanced/setting-up-multi-sites)

Answer (score 0):

Each Joomla installation has 1 `configuration.php`. This file contains the database details for your site. Seeing as Joomla can only use 1 database out the box, each site will require a different installation.

Comment: this is wrong - many sites on 1 single Joomla installation is possible

Comment: @FFrewin key phrase was `out the box` ;) But yes, you're right, it can be done. Either way, I would never recommend using 1 installation for various reasons.