# 2 domains, 2 templates one cms with same content

Tags: joomla-3.x, cms, multi-sites

I have a site that need to have two sites in one, it is one company with two brands the one is news paper and the other one is tv(video). They have corresponding articles or videos, that feature on both sites.

I have set up 2 templates but when I click to go to the article on the video it shows the article with the news paper template.

Is there a way to set it up that if an article is featured on both templates that when it is published one time and shows on both templates?

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly you want to publish an article on Site A but have it appear on Site B also?

Comment: yes that is corect

Comment: This seems fit your requirements http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/content-sharing/articles-sharing/simple-sharing

Answer (score 1):

It might be clearer if you explain how you have set up 2 domains and 2 templates with one Joomla installation.

In any case, you should be able to set up separate menu options that point to the same article and assign the relevant templates in the template settings.

It may be easier to set this up using a multi site extension such as [Virtual Domains](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/virtual-domains) or similar if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved that using [Multi-Sites](http://extensions.joomla.org/tags/multiple-sites) extensions. I have tried the [Mighty-Sites](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/mightysites) and [Joomla Multi-Sites](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/multi-sites).

Both can be configured to share database content - although Multi-sites will require additional plugin to share Joomla articles.

I also trust Neil's opinion about the Virtual Domains, although I have never tried that extension - I have seen him speaking highly on it in other posts, where he explains its options:
[Multiple website managment with Joomla?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/multiple-website-managment-with-joomla/14799#14799)

Also, the one that Johnny_s shared with his comment - [simple article sharing](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/content-sharing/articles-sharing/simple-sharing) seems a promising one.

## Update

Links to connect this with other relevant Q/A:

- [Multiple website managment with Joomla?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/multiple-website-managment-with-joomla/14782#14782)
- [How to update an online website?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16547/how-to-update-an-online-website/16551#16551)
- [Mass Joomla sites Updates / Maintenance](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16264/mass-joomla-sites-updates-maintenance/16267#16267)
- [Single source many Joomla sites on a server. How could it be possible?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4809/single-source-many-joomla-sites-on-a-server-how-could-it-be-possible/4837#4837)
- [Is there a way to promote articles between environments?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/419/is-there-a-way-to-promote-articles-between-environments)
- [How do you update a website once it has gone live?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/126/how-do-you-update-a-website-once-it-has-gone-live/135#135)

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a great idea for a plugin.  You could have a single site mapped to multiple domain names and let the plugin assign the template based on the domain used to visit the site.  Configuration could be as easy as adding a single entry - domain=template.  As many domains as you like.

That would be super easy to write too...two or three hours tops after testing