# Different database for different subdomains but same files

Tags: joomla-3.x, multi-sites

I want to make a website that uses the same joomla files but different websites for each subdomain. I figured this approach is best for a multi website installation. Each subsite is a simple site that frontend users can create/edit articles from certain categories or upload images and files (for download). Also the database content (users, articles, images) is not shared between subsites. The reason I want the same files is that so I can edit the template files all at once, for instance to manually insert a common banner for all websites. I know that if I want to install a plugin for all the sites, I will have to manually install and configure them on each subsite, but I see no alternative.
 
What I want to know if this is possible.
I am also opened for suggestions on different approaches. (If any extensions are involved I would preffer free ones.)

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/multiple-website-managment-with-joomla/14799#14799

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10911/2-domains-2-templates-one-cms-with-same-content/16312#16312

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16938/joomla-staging-and-multiple-site-management/16940#16940

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/multiple-website-managment-with-joomla/14799#14799

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, but there is no free extension for such a mighty task.

I have used [AlterBrains MightySites](https://alterbrains.com/joomla-extensions/administration/multisites-manager) extension before, in various [Case Scenarios](https://alterbrains.com/joomla-extensions/administration/multisites-manager/case-studies), with a great success.

MightySites is Joomla! multisites manager and allows you to have multiple sites running in single hosting account and share database data between different Joomla! sites, with following features:

- Single login/logout on websites.
- No hacks of core files are required and no Joomla! core files are patched.
- Ability to use database content, users (with Community Builder and JomSocial support) from other sites.
- You can have many Joomla! websites using a single hosting account, with same users and JomSocial contents but with different template style etc.
- You can easily replicate your current website into other website without building new hosting account!

MightySites is used for 2 main tasks:

- Run multiple Joomla websites from single hosting account (all sites use same files but different database data).
- Sharing of database contents (multiple sites can use same database tables, so these data are always same across all sites).

Highly Recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Seblod Multisites Feature](https://www.seblod.com/resources/manuals/advanced/setting-up-multi-sites) is capable for that and it's free. But the learning curve is steep (but it's worth it)