# Mass Joomla sites Updates / Maintenance

Tags: joomla-3.x, update, administration, one-click-updates, maintenance

I have around 100 websites on a single server, all in **j3.2.x** all working fine.

Now if i want to add a single **module/component/plugin** in all the websites i have to log-in in all the websites and add the respective **module/component/plugin**.

Is there a way to update all the websites in one click or through copying folders or updating the database...??

or any other way to apply the changes to all the websites??? because going to all the websites and applying the changes is a lot of work.

Answer (score 4):

I could suggest the following:

1. [**Watchful.li**](http://Watchful.li)

A subscription based service, to monitor, audit, backup, manage, update Joomla sites remotely from a single location. You install the Watchful.li client into your sites and start using the service.

2. **Joomla Multi-Sites**

You can setup your sites under a Multi-Sites environment, if your scenario is fitting in.

2 of the most common fits are the following:

- If sites are under the same hosting account, you could look into developing the Multi-Sites environment, especially if they have similar features/purpose, and you still need to create more similar websites.
- If sites are under the same server (not hosting) but still have similar features/ purpose, you could put them under a single hosting account in a MS setup.

Setting up Multi-sites will require some work, and it won't be that easy in the beginning, but if the use-case is a good fit, it will make things much more flexible in the future and at the end you will have to maintain a single Joomla installation.

Here you find extensions for [**Multi-Sites**](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/core-enhancements/multiple-sites).

## Update

Links to other relevant Q/A in JSE:

- [Multiple website managment with Joomla?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/multiple-website-managment-with-joomla/14782#14782)
- [2 domains, 2 templates one cms with same content](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10911/2-domains-2-templates-one-cms-with-same-content/16312#16312)
- [How to update an online website?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16547/how-to-update-an-online-website/16551#16551)
- [Single source many Joomla sites on a server. How could it be possible?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4809/single-source-many-joomla-sites-on-a-server-how-could-it-be-possible/4837#4837)
- [Is there a way to promote articles between environments?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/419/is-there-a-way-to-promote-articles-between-environments)
- [How do you update a website once it has gone live?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/126/how-do-you-update-a-website-once-it-has-gone-live/135#135)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @FFrewin, another solution for updating extensions on a large number of Joomla websites is [mysites.guru](https://mysites.guru) (formerly myjoomla.com).

**Manual Updates**

You can update all copies of a particular extension on all the websites you have set up in myjoomla.com:

[image: mysites.guru]

**Automatic Updates**

You can also enable automatic updates for a select but growing list of extensions:

[image: mysites.guru]

Answer (score 0):

As at August 2018, Geraint Edwards has released [YourSites Manager](https://extensions.joomla.org/browse/new/extension/yoursites-manager) which is reasonably priced and allows you to administer multiple Joomla websites from a central console including:

- Checking for Joomla updates
- Checking for extension updates
- Initiating a new backup
- Installing a new extension
- Applying Joomla updates
- Applying extension updates

There is a demo site so you can try out the extension to make sure it does what you need before purchasing:

[image: YourSites Manager]