# Joomla Staging and Multiple site management?

Tags: joomla-3.x, multi-sites

Good Morning all, i was wonder if anyone is aware of an open source joomla management solution for multiple sites similar to [Cloudaccess](http://www.cloudaccess.net/products/joomla-hosting-support.html) or [MyJoomla](https://myjoomla.com/)?
 I cannot seem to find anything? Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Regards
Donna

Comment: You also can manage multiple sites via extensions, find some options here: http://extensions.joomla.org/category/core-enhancements/multiple-sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked again in this website in various forms. Here is a list of relative questions with answers to your question.

[Multiple website managment with Joomla?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/multiple-website-managment-with-joomla/14782#14782)

[2 domains, 2 templates one cms with same content](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10911/2-domains-2-templates-one-cms-with-same-content/16312#16312)

[How to update an online website?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16547/how-to-update-an-online-website/16551#16551)

[Mass Joomla sites Updates / Maintenance](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16264/mass-joomla-sites-updates-maintenance/16267#16267)

[Single source many Joomla sites on a server. How could it be possible?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4809/single-source-many-joomla-sites-on-a-server-how-could-it-be-possible/4837#4837)

[Is there a way to promote articles between environments?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/419/is-there-a-way-to-promote-articles-between-environments)

[How do you update a website once it has gone live?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/126/how-do-you-update-a-website-once-it-has-gone-live/135#135)

Comment: This is not regarding multiple websites with the same source. the articles above do not appear relevant. I am looking for a control panel which will allow me to view all of my completely independant Joomla sites. They are not linked in anyway and having different hosting accounts. I have found https://watchful.li bu tthis again is a paid solution, i have my own server so i was hoping there might be an opensource control panel to do this.

Comment: @Dtorr1981: You confused me. Multiple sites but not multi-sites..., staging, myJoomla, cloudaccess or watchful.li. These are all different things. The links above are all relevant one way or another. Your particular business needs might be subject of deep research and a lot of personal work and development. All the above services have developed their own solutions. I doubt you can find something free at this level.

Comment: @Dtorr1981: MyJoomla is not multiple sites but for monitoring sites against malware. Cloudaccess provides hosting with the web application of your choice installed. Not sure if they give any kind of central tool, to watch all your installations. I guess both have implemented their own workflows. Watchful.li might be close to what you want to do. Obviously there was too much work to develop it, so such things can't be free. So if you want something for free to setup your business, then you will have to develop it yourself.

Comment: apologies for the confusion. I am currently looking at the trial of watchful.li which seems to fulfil my needs. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @Dtorr1981: Everything is ok no worries... If I have understood right, watchful.li will be what you need. Good luck with your research and business.

Comment: @FFrewin MyJoomla is not only against malware, but is a suite comparable to watchful.li. You can mass backup and upsates sites, extension etc. With the great feature of "audit" websites for malware.